# What is the default socket-time value in uWSGI

Tags: sockets, nginx, uwsgi

We are running into very similar problem with this question:

[nginx 502 error and 504 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441459/nginx-502-error-and-504-error)

The problem is we are getting 502 instead of 504 for some longer requests, say 20 seconds, then it returns 502 to the browser, but the Nginx timeout is set to 60 seconds to wait for the uWSGI's response.

We looked at the logs and we can see this error:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected
```

Looks like the socket has been closed, so based on the SO link above, I stumbled onto this setting http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#socket-timeout but I am unable to find out the default value to validate my claim.

Can anyone please shed some light on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is from the uwsgi side, we changed the `socket-timeout` to 60 seconds but still got 502, and it turned out to be `harakiri` mode set to 30 seconds timeout to kill the workers. Changed that to 60 seconds and made the view to sleep for 90 seconds and got 504 from nginx, which was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this:

It seems like the default value for `socket-timeout` is 4 seconds:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/init.c#L128

Although for my case that translated to 8-12 seconds which is probably due to some technical detail that I don't understand.